# Finding and optimal way of distributing dictionary changes over the network

Tags: c++, c, architecture, dictionary

The problem: You have a big dictionary on the server and you are distributing it to lots of clients.

The dictionary is updated only on the server side but you want to allow the clients to update the dictionary by minimizing the data being transfered.

Also you can assume that you have a huge number of clients requesting updates, probably daily or so.

If a key is removed from the server you expect it to be removed from the client on sync.

**How would you solve this problem?**

Additional request: the solution should be easy to implement on **different platforms** including desktop (Windows,Linux,OS X) and mobile ones (iOS, Android,...). If this request the usage of third-party library their license has to be very liberal, like BSD.

Answer (score 0):

If this is at a file level, you use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) (or the awesome [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) or [xdelta](http://xdelta.org/) or such).

If this is at an application level, then one approach is to write journal updates to the dictionary (key-value-store) in the server - you write a log of all updates, adds and removes in the order they occur.  Your clients then periodically hit the server and say the position in the log they last received, and the server sends them all log items newer than that.  The server may also skip journal items that are superseded (e.g. an add that was later removed).  If the server keeps track of the clients, it can keep track of the minimum client journal position, and so get rid of journal items it doesn't need any more.

If the dictionary is large and yet requests are low, the clients can just hit the server for each lookup and always get the newest key.  This often scales better than you imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you can find a solution that supports your requirements rather than build your own.

I suggest that you take a look at CouchDB. It has the following features that make it relevant for your problem imo:

- It's a key-value store = dictionary, so should easily fit your data model.
- Supports replication from machine to machine (or multiple machines) in an occasionally connected environment. That should fit your use case of clients connecting to a server once    in a while to pull all updates.
- Works well in a distributed environment, so you should be able to handle the huge number of clients, e.g. by maintaining several servers.
- Good scaling - works on servers and any kind of client (including mobile). Also, runs on multiple OSs.
- It has a rather efficient data protocol for the replication process.
- It's free.